# Is it possible to find the local computer in AD without hardcoding its domain?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm using C# to find my local computer's `objectGuid` by querying Active Directory.  To do this, I'm currently using a `DirectorySearcher`, passing it a (hardcoded) path as the search root, and then filtering by computer name:

```
string adRootPath = @"LDAP://OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=baz,DC=com";    
DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry(adRootPath);

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(adRoot);
searcher.Filter = @"(&(objectCategory=Computer)(CN=" + Environment.MachineName + "))";
```

I don't want to hardcode the search root, and was wondering if there is a better way.  I thought about just using an empty search root, but I was worried that computer names may not always be unique across different domains.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a ComputerPrincipal 
// and with the name of "MyPC"
ComputerPrincipal cp = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx);
cp.Name = "MyPC";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(cp);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: Thanks.  Will FindAll() be guaranteed to find only one result (that being the local computer), even if there are duplicate computer names across different OU's?

Comment: @Eric: no, `FindAll()` will find **all** occurences that match the criteria specified (as its name implies). You can then inspect e.g. the `DistinguishedName` property on the `ComputerPrincipal` to see where in the AD tree that computer lives. There's also a `.FindOne()` method that returns the first match - but you might not know that there are other computers out there matching your criteria.

Comment: Ah I see.  Well, I'm actually just trying to find the *local* computer's AD information.  It seems that with this method, I would have no way of distinguishing which computer is the local computer in my results.

Comment: @Eric: I don't know for sure - I'm not a network admin - but I have a hunch that the computers also need to have "unique" names within the domain - just like the "samAccountName" of each user and group must be unique, across all OU's. Also: why don't you test this?? Try assigning `cp.Name = Environment.MachineName` and let the code run and do a `FindAll()` - does it find more than one computer??

Comment: I asked this on another question (testing would only tell me if my own computer had a duplicate, but I need to know more generally), and yes computer names are unique within the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the domain by just calling RootDse.

This site has a good example - [Site with an example of RootDSE](http://cyrusbuilt.net/wordpress/?p=195)