# Get OU (Organizational Unit) name that a local computer belongs to using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, ou

I need to find out the name of the OU that the local computer (that is connected to the Active Directory) belongs to using WinAPI/C++. Any ideas?

Comment: If managed C++ is an option, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314496/is-it-possible-to-find-the-local-computer-in-ad-without-hardcoding-its-domain

Comment: Thanks, but no, managed C++ is NOT an option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple WINAPI (not COM) way to acces Active Directory in C or C++ see [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

```
void AfficheErreurLdap(char *fonction, ULONG rc);

/*
*
*       Fonction d'entrée du programme 
*
*/

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  LDAP *pSessionLdap;    // Pointeur vers la session LDAP
  char *pHote;           // Pointeur vers la chaîne représentant le nom de l'hôte   
  char *pUtilisateur;    // Pointeur vers la chaîne représentant l'utilisateur  
  char *pMotDePasse;     // Pointeur vers la chaîne représentant le mot de passe
  char *pRacineLdap;     // Pointeur vers la racine Ldap
  ULONG rc;                // Récupération du code de retour des appels
  LDAPMessage   *pResultat; // Pointeur vers le message résultat de la réquête LDAP
  LDAPMessage   *pEntree;     // Utilisée lors du parcours du résultat pour l'affichage

  char *pDN;                 // Pointeur vers le DN d'une entrée du résultat
  char *pAttribut;     // Pointeur vers la chaîne représentant l'attribut
  BerElement *pBer = NULL;// "curseur" interne à l'API LDAP pour le parcours des elts 
  char **pValeurs;            // Valeurs de l'attribut lors de l'affichage du résultat
  int    i;                             // Indice pour la parcours des valeurs  d'attribut

  /* Analyse des Paramètres de lancement et affichage d’un message d’erreur si incorrect */
  if (argc != 5)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Syntaxe :\n\tex_cldap_1 Hote Utilisateur MotDePasse RacineLdap\n");
    exit (1);
  }
  /* Récupération des paramètres des lancement  */
  pHote = argv[1];
  pUtilisateur = argv[2];
  pMotDePasse = argv[3];
  pRacineLdap = argv[4];

  /* Ouverture de la session LDAP et récupération du handle de session */
  pSessionLdap = ldap_open( pHote, 389);    /* 389 est le numéro de port standard LDAP */

  if ( pSessionLdap == NULL ) 
  {
    // En cas d'erreur : affichage du message d'erreur adéquat 
    perror( "ldap_open" );
    exit( 2 );
  }

  printf("Ouverture de la session réalisée\n");

  /* Authentification du client                                                                                                             */
  /* Pour l'exemple, l'authentification est faite en tant qu'anonyme    */
  rc = ldap_simple_bind_s(pSessionLdap, pUtilisateur, pMotDePasse);
  if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) 
  {
    // Erreur lors de l'authentification, on termine après affichage d'un message
    AfficheErreurLdap("ldap_simple_bind_s", rc);

    exit( 3 );
  }

  printf("Authentification réalisée\n");

  /*                                                                                                                                */
  /* Recherche des données dans l'annuaire                  */
  /*                                                                                                                                */
  rc = ldap_search_s(pSessionLdap,            // Session LDAP
    pRacineLdap,                    // Base de la recherche
    LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, // Sccpe : LDAP_SCOPE_BASE, LDAP_SCOPE_ONELEVEL, LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE  
    "(objectClass=*)",      // Filtre de recherche
    NULL,                               // Attributs que l'on souhaite visualiser
    0,                                      // Indique si l'on souhaite uniquement les types (1) ou 
    // Les attributs et les valeurs (0)
    &pResultat ) ;              // Pointeur vers le résultat

  if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) 
  {
    // Erreur lors de la recherche, on termine après affichage du message d'erreur
    AfficheErreurLdap("ldap_search_s", rc);
    exit (4);
  }

  printf("Requête réalisée\n");


  /* On va maintenant parcourir le résultat et afficher les couples */
  /* attributs, valeurs                                                                                                                         */

  pEntree = ldap_first_entry( pSessionLdap, pResultat );

  while (pEntree != NULL)
  {
    // Récupération du DN, et affichage de celui-ci
    pDN = ldap_get_dn( pSessionLdap, pEntree );
    if ( pDN != NULL ) 
    {
      printf( "dn: %s\n", pDN );

      // Libération de la mémoire allouée par l'API LDAP
      ldap_memfree( pDN );  
    }


    // Pour chaque attribut, on va lire le couple attribut, valeur 
    pAttribut = ldap_first_attribute( pSessionLdap, pEntree, &pBer );
    while (  pAttribut != NULL)
    {
      // Récupération des valeurs associées à un attribut 
      pValeurs = ldap_get_values( pSessionLdap, pEntree, pAttribut);

      if (pValeurs  != NULL ) 
      {
        for ( i = 0; pValeurs[i] != NULL; i++ ) 
          printf( "%s: %s\n", pAttribut, pValeurs[i]);

        // Libération des valeurs lues 
        ldap_value_free( pValeurs ); 
      }

      // Libération de la mémoire utilisée par l'attribut 
      ldap_memfree( pAttribut );    

      // Lecture de l'attribut suivant
      pAttribut = ldap_next_attribute( pSessionLdap, pEntree, pBer );
    }

    // Passage à la ligne dans l'affichage
    printf( "\n\n" );

    // Récupération de l'entrée suivante de l'annuaire
    pEntree = ldap_next_entry( pSessionLdap, pEntree );
  }

  // Libération du message de résultat
  ldap_msgfree( pResultat );

  /* Fin de la session LDAP     */
  ldap_unbind( pSessionLdap );
}


/*
*
* Fonction permettant d'afficher les erreurs des opérations LDAP 
*
*
*/
void AfficheErreurLdap(char *fonction, ULONG rc)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"Erreur LDAP dans la fonction '%s', Code : %ld (0x%xld)\n", fonction, rc,rc);
}
```

Comment: To add up to what's been said above, just found this page on escaping "bad" characters in the DN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this is fairly simple: connect to the server with [`ADsOpenObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772238.aspx), instantiate an [`IDirectorySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746362.aspx) and invoke its [`ExecuteSearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746365.aspx) method, then use [`GetFirstRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746368.aspx) and [`GetNextRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746370.aspx) to walk through the result data (but for this query, you'll only expect one row).

In reality, however, all of this is COM -- so expect those half dozen (or so) function calls to be pretty much lost in at least a hundred lines of COM-cruftiness (and by the time the code is solid and robust, don't be surprised if it's closer to 1000 lines, most of which have no noticeable connection to Active Directory).

I should add that there are almost certainly other ways to do this -- as I recall, MS provides at least two or three different ways to access LDAP-type data. When I wrote some code for this, I initially tried to find which would be the cleanest, but gave up in frustration. There seemed to be no hope for cleanest -- at least at that time, I settled for "ugly but somewhat documented".

Answer (score 0):

```
    ///////////////IDirectorySearch///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CComPtr<IDirectorySearch> pDSSearch;

hr = ADsGetObject( L"LDAP://DC=forest,DC=internal", 
    IID_IDirectorySearch, 
    (void**) &pDSSearch );

if ( !SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    return 0;
}

LPWSTR pszAttr[] = { L"description", L"Name", L"distinguishedname" };
ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch;
DWORD dwCount = 0;
ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;
DWORD dwAttrNameSize = sizeof(pszAttr)/sizeof(LPWSTR);

// Search for all objects with the 'cn' property  TESTCOMP.
hr = pDSSearch->ExecuteSearch(L"(&(objectClass=computer)(cn=TESTCOMP))",pszAttr ,dwAttrNameSize,&hSearch );

LPWSTR pszColumn;
while( pDSSearch->GetNextRow( hSearch) != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS )
{
    // Get the property.
    hr = pDSSearch->GetColumn( hSearch, L"distinguishedname", &col );

    // If this object supports this attribute, display it.
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    { 
        if (col.dwADsType == ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING)
            wprintf(L"The description property:%s\r\n", col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString); 
        pDSSearch->FreeColumn( &col );
    }
    else
        puts("description property NOT available");
    puts("------------------------------------------------");
    dwCount++;
}
pDSSearch->CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);
///////////////IDirectorySearch///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

In this search you'll get

(*((col).pADsValues)).DNString
"CN=TESTCOMP,OU=OUnit3,OU=OUnit,DC=forest,DC=internal"

So this is path to your TESTCOMP and I believe OUnit3 is what you want.